# LSF Memory environment variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, lsf

does anyone know the environment variable LSF uses to store the ram allocation for a job?

The LSF documentation lists out `$LSB_JOB_MEMLIMIT`, however, this one isn't present in the LSF batch or interactive sessions.  The closest environment variable is `$LSB_CG_MEMLIMIT` which is set to `0x200000000`. However, how does one convert `0x200000000` to get `8` or `8G` in *bash*?  any help would be most appreciated. I'm trying to pass the maximum memory allocation as an argument to a tool inside the batch script. Any help would be most appreciated -- thank you

```
> echo $LS
$LSB_ACCT_FILE            $LSB_DJOB_RANKFILE        $LSB_EXIT_REQUEUE         $LSB_JOBRES_CALLBACK      $LSB_SUB_HOST             $LSF_BINDIR               $LSFUSER
$LSB_AFFINITY_HOSTFILE    $LSB_DOCKER_JOB_STARTTS   $LSB_HOSTS                $LSB_JOBRES_PID           $LSB_SUB_RES_REQ          $LSF_CGROUP_TOPDIR_KEY    $LSF_VERSION
$LSB_APPLICATION_NAME     $LSB_ECHKPNT_RSH_CMD      $LSB_INTERACTIVE          $LSB_MAX_NUM_PROCESSORS   $LSB_SUB_USER             $LSF_ENVDIR               $LS_JOBPID
$LSB_BATCH_JID            $LSB_EEXEC_REAL_GID       $LSB_JOB_EXECUSER         $LSB_MCPU_HOSTS           $LSB_TRAPSIGS             $LSF_INVOKE_CMD           $LS_SUBCWD
$LSB_BIND_CPU_LIST        $LSB_EEXEC_REAL_UID       $LSB_JOBEXIT_STAT         $LSB_OUTDIR               $LSB_UNIXGROUP_INT        $LSF_JOB_TIMESTAMP_VALUE  
$LSB_CG_MEMLIMIT          $LSB_EFFECTIVE_RSRCREQ    $LSB_JOBFILENAME          $LSB_PROJECT_NAME         $LSB_XFER_OP              $LSF_LIBDIR               
$LSB_CHKFILENAME          $LSB_EXEC_CLUSTER         $LSB_JOBID                $LSB_QUEUE                $LS_COLORS                $LSF_LIM_API_NTRIES       
$LSB_DJOB_HOSTFILE        $LSB_EXEC_HOSTTYPE        $LSB_JOBINDEX             $LSB_RES_GET_FANOUT_INFO  $LS_EXECCWD               $LSF_LOGDIR               
$LSB_DJOB_NUMPROC         $LSB_EXIT_PRE_ABORT       $LSB_JOBNAME              $LSB_SHMODE               $LS_EXEC_T                $LSF_SERVERDIR   
         
> echo $LSB_CG_MEMLIMIT 
0x200000000

> bsub -V
IBM Spectrum LSF 10.1.0.0 build 545500, Apr 10 2020
Copyright International Business Machines Corp. 1992, 2016.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that hex value 0x200000000 is decimal 8589934592. Which is exactly 8 GB. Bash recognizes hex literals. So you can convert the value to decimal MB like this:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $(( $LSB_CG_MEMLIMIT / 1024 / 1024))'
8192
```